# How to find probability of sequence given probability of each possible element

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

Let's say I have a set of four shapes of different colors in a bag, but I'm not sure which shapes are in the bag. I think there is a 0.01 chance of a red square, 0.13 chance of a red circle, etc. These are the probabilities for each shape being in the bag:

```
P(red square) = 0.01
P(red circle) = 0.13
P(green square) = 0.35
P(green triangle) = 0.35
P(blue diamond) = 0.01
P(blue circle) = 0.09
P(yellow circle) = 0.05
P(yellow circle) = 0.01
```

If I pull out all four shapes, one at a time, what's the probability that I will not draw a red shape?

This isn't a problem from a book, I'm trying to learn how to solve this type of problem.

**Edit**

This is a simple example, but how would you solve this same problem if there were 15 things in the bag, and 50 possible things? That's a lot of combinations that would have to be evaluated, just wondering if there is a faster method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me assume that you put (blindfolded) 4 shapes in the bag from a very large  lot.

Since there are only $4$ shapes in the bag, you "pull out **all** four shapes, one at a time" (presumably without replacement) and you want P(draw no red), it is possible only if all $4$ shapes are non-red, which is $0.86^4$

*Re your edit:*

Assuming you want to draw 4 out of 15.

Firstly, you can convert it to just two types: red and non-red.

Secondly, if you know how many of these 2 types are in the bag, it is a simple hypergeometric.

Thirdly, if it is not, I don't know of a futher shortcut, unless the expected value of reds in the bag turns out to be an integer.

Comment: If you have something else in mind, pl. clarify.

Comment: Please see my edit, I'm mainly wondering if there is a way to solve this without evaluating all possible outcomes.

Comment: I marked your answer as the answer because I'm going to use a hypergeometric as an approximation when there are a large number of combinations. It's only an approximation though because exact combinations aren't correct when each shape has a different probability and removing one affects the probability of the others. I suspect this is just a computationally hard problem (or beyond my current math skills). Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome !

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider a number of cases since you pull the shapes out at different times.

You seek to find the probability that you don't pull a red shape. That's like saying you don't pull a red shape first AND you don't pull a red shape second AND so on.

What's the probability that you don't draw a red shape in the first block? That's $0.86 = 1 - (0.01 + 0.13)$.

Now it gets tricky because you need to find the probability that you don't draw a red shape in the second block. However, since you've already drawn your first shape, you need to take that into account. So if you draw a green shape first, your probability of not drawing a red shape in the second block is 1 - (0.14/0.65) which is about 0.7846.

More formally, you're using conditional probabilities.

$P(A \text{ and } B \text{ and } C \text{ and } D) = P(D|C \text{ and } B \text{ and } A)*P(C|B \text{ and } A)*P(B|A)*P(A)$.

The difficulty lies in that A, B, and C (the first, second, and third "blocks") may vary depending on what shape is pulled.

A tree diagram might be the best way to organize your thoughts and make sure you don't miss a possible combination.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please see my edit, I'm mainly wondering if there is a way to solve this without evaluating all possible outcomes.